# Select box opening input box jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to open a have a select box show an input box when certain options are selected.

Here is my code:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $('input.other').hide();
    $('#amount').change(function() {
        // var val = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        //alert(val);
        var selectedValue = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        //alert(selectedValue);
        if( $(this).selectedValue == '25.00') {
            // only if the radio button has a dob-field
            $('input.other').show();// show only the following first
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: There are many errors in your code. It is `$(document).ready(function() {})`. It is not `if ($(this).selectedValue == '25.00')` but `if (selectedValue == '25.00')`... And `$('input.other').show()` just negates what you did on the second line.

Comment: Could you try to rephrase the first sentence? It doesn't make a lot of sense in the current form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target the selected `option` inside the `#amount` element directly by using the selector below, and find it's value and compare it all inside the if statement.

The problem with the code in the question is `$(this).selectedValue`, where `$(this)` is referring to `#amount` and not the `option`, and `selectedValue` is a variable, and should be used directly, but it's not really necessary to use a variable here, as it's fully readable and straight forward to do everything inside the if statement.

```
$('input.other').hide();
$('#amount').on('change', function(){
    if( $(':selected', this).val() == '25.00') {
        $('input.other').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: You might want to add some explanation what his mistake was and what your code does. That way your answer will be of use to future generations of developers as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `selectedValue` to check not `$(this).selectedValue`

```
if( selectedValue == '25.00') { // only if the radio button has a dob-field
 $('input.other').show();// show only the following first
}
```

Here is a full working snippet

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.other').hide();
        var selectedValue = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        if( selectedValue == '25.00') {
            // only if the radio button has a dob-field
            $('input.other').show();// show only the following first
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: When the document loads the input box with the class of other is showing with your code.

Comment: @user1235905, no that is your code. I dont want to step outside the scope of the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.val()` directly on the `SELECT` instead of selecting the `:selected` `OPTION` (assuming that `#amount` is a `SELECT` element):

```
var input = $('input.other').hide();
$('#amount').change(function() {
    if( $(this).val() == '25.00') {
        input.show();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bj6MJ/

**Added:** assuming that you want to hide it again if the user selects something else than "25.00", you can use `toggle()`:

```
var input = $('input.other').hide();
$('#amount').change(function() {
    input.toggle( $(this).val() == '25.00' );
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bj6MJ/1/